# RESTful two-phase commit?

Tags: rest, distributed-transactions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transaction in REST WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389881/transaction-in-rest-wcf-service)

http://rest.blueoxen.net/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?TwoPhaseCommit proposed implementing two-phase commits using a custom header value to identify the transaction associated with a request. Wouldn't this approach break caching proxies? For example, a proxy sees `HTTP DELETE /foo` against Transaction 123 but it's not smart enough to realize this transaction is subsequently rolled-back. The proxy then proceeds to cache the fact that `/foo` has been deleted.

Am I wrong? What do you recommend for implementing RESTful two-phase commits?

Comment: See my answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389881/transaction-in-rest-wcf-service) question

Comment: Why does Fielding assume that two-phased commits can only be implemented with the client coordinating server resources? I see nothing wrong with two-phased commits (or transactions in general) from a RESTful point of view. Please clarify what he means.

Comment: Note to self, interesting post: http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/06/rest-ts

Comment: Damn. I wrote you a big comment and power outage trashed it.  Here's the condensed version.  Seems I read Roy's quote wrong.  I don't think he is saying you can't do dist-transactions, he is just saying that the client does not need to be aware of any dist-trans protocol.  The client simply follows the links it has been given.  If behind the scenes some kind of 2-phase commit is going on, maybe that is ok.  Need to do some more thinking.

Comment: interesting! Let me know if you find any more documentation on this.